# How can i set orderby in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, sql-order-by

This is my code ,here how can i give orderby .

`$this->set('added', $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing', array('status = 0', 'assigned_by = '.$user_level)));`

Here i want to give `order by TravancoMarketing.id DESC`

How can i give this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller you should declare something like this:

```
public $paginate = array(
        'order' => array(
            'TravancoMarketing.id' => 'DESC'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either add it as the default order by to the TravancoMarketing model:

```
class TravancoMarketing {

    public $order = array('TravancoMarketing.id'=>'DESC');

}
```

or to the paginate query itself:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'TravancoMarketing.status'=>0,
        'TravancoMarketing.assigned_by'=>$user_level
    ),
    'order'=>array(
        'TravancoMarketing.id'=>'DESC'
    )
);

$this->set('added', $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing'));
```